# How to reference secrets in Azure Container Apps from Vite (VueJS)

Tags: vuejs3, vite, azure-container-apps

I am trying to access it as recommended here: [https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#:~:text=console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY)%20//%20123](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#:%7E:text=console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY)%20//%20123)

The problem is how do I pass Environment variables to VITE after the container image is built?

I tried creating Variables like:

`APP_API_KEY` and assign a value to it.

On my code, I try to call it with `import.meta.env.APP_API_KEY`

But all I get is `undefined`.

tried to follow this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72705471/how-to-reference-secrets-in-azure-container-apps?rq=1#:~:text=let%20db_password%20%3D%20process.env.DB_PASSWORD%3B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72705471/how-to-reference-secrets-in-azure-container-apps?rq=1#:%7E:text=let%20db_password%20%3D%20process.env.DB_PASSWORD%3B)

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

prefix with `VITE_`

[vite env-variable docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files)

Comment: That would work during BUILD, but not after - as these are simply read from the environment and then injected into dist

Comment: Azure doesn't allow "_" in the secret key name. So how do we get around this?